# Can I use Passport.js and client-side facebook-authentification?

Tags: node.js

I'm building a REST-api that uses facebook for authentication, I think the best solution to be platform agnostic is to let the client deal with retrieving an auth-token from facebook and then use that to authenticate, to keep the API as clean as possible.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token) strategy instead of [passport-facebook](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook).

In this way you can get the token on the client-side and send it to the application using:

```
app.post('/auth/facebook/token',
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token'),
    function(req, res) {
        // do something with req.user
        res.send(req.user ? 200 : 401);
    }
);
```

With the code above you can pass the token using a query parameter like `GET /auth/facebook/token?access_token=<TOKEN_HERE>`, putting on the HTTP header access_token or in the request body.

Comment: Precise one mate : )